# C# unit testing IOexception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, ioexception

I am struggling to create a unit test of this nature:

```
 [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(IOException))]
       public void FileNotFound_ThrowsIOException()
       {
    }
```

The bit I need to test is the following:

```
[public static List<blah> ParseBlahdata()
       {
           List<blah> blahs = new List<blah>();
           var read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(webpage));
           var parse = new CsvParser(read);
           while (true)
           {
               var row = parse.Read();
               if (row == null)
               {
                   break;
               }
               blahs.Add(new blah(row[0]));
           }
           return blahs;
       }
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: To start with you would probably want to change the method signature to have the `webpage` passed in as a dependency. Or have some other way or introducing this dependency, maybe via a constructor.  You can then test your method with a `webpage` that you know would cause an exception to be thrown.

Comment: Also why do you want to test an `IOException` are you expecting there could be such an exception?  Are you sure you're not wanting to test for a `FileNotFoundException`?  `File.OpenRead' throws a lot of different exceptions.

Comment: Hey @Darren, thank you for your comments but what I meant was opening a file with some text really, and yes the framework for the test is what I need to test... But I am not quite sure how to.